# No se puede ver un reporte jasperreport en red local

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Terminé mi proyecto: todo funciona muy bien; a través de la red local realiza el CRUD completo en los equipos de red que poseemos en la casa (1 Pc y dos notebook), el PC realiza la tarea de servidor local y también puede ser utilizado para otras funciones (no es dedicado), en los restantes uno puede entrar al programa sin problema y realizar todo proceso. Cabe mencionar que se realizó el jar sin problema, después al .exe a través de launch4j y posteriormente utilizando el innosetup para realizar la instalación en los otros equipos. Todo funciona bien: se puede grabar, leer, modificar, eliminar, pero no se puede ver los reportes hechos en jasperreport, solo en el pc que hace de servidor local. Se hace mención que se utiliza netbeans 8.2, el itext 5.4.0 y el jasperreport 6.13.0.

A continuación se muestran los `import` utilizados para el jasper.

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
```

este es el código que se utiliza para llamar al .jasper, el cual funciona muy bien y no presenta problema.

```
private void cmdimprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int desicion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea imprimir esta Cotización de Repuestos?");
    switch (desicion) {
        case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            try {
                MyConnection cn = new MyConnection();
                Connection conn = cn.getConnection();
                JasperReport reporte = null;
                String path = "src/Archivos_Consorcio/cotizacion.jasper";
                Map parametros = new HashMap();
                parametros.put("siniestro", txtsiniestro.getText());
                reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Archivos_Consorcio/cotizacion.jasper"));
                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, conn);
                JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
                view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                view.setVisible(true);
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frmcoticonsorcio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No imprimir");
            break;
    }
}
```

y este es el listado completo de las librerías que se utilizan actualmente.
[image: vista de librerías]
[image: segunda parte de las librerías]

Siempre dicen que hay que agregar más librerías de jasperreport y lo hice, pero sigue sin mostrar los reportes en la red local.

Averiguando (doy gracias al asesoramiento que me brindo @sal), el error es el siguiente: no me carga la imagen del reporte en los equipos de red local. Este es el código que se utiliza en el xml:

```xml
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="83" height="77" uuid="aed2fd9d-f549-4ded-9d87-efdf324a8047"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Oficina\\src\\imagenes\\Logo consorcio.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

y al investigar a través de internet me encontré con esta solución:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{path} + "/imagenes/cabecera.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

lo hago y lo cambio en el mismo xml y al realizar la prueba, ─es decir con la vista previa─ no funciona, y lo otro: la imagen lo deja como campo nulo.

Comment: Es útil conocer el mensaje de error.

Comment: @sal te comento que no da ningún error, solo no lo muestra , por eso puse los import que se manejan con los jasper pensando que faltaba alguno , o las librerías que faltaba alguno, además del código, por eso es el problema que da, cabe hacer mención que todos los equipos de la red e incluso el del servidor utilizan el .exe, y vuelvo hacer hincapié que el único que ve los reportes de jasper el servidor local, ojala que me puedan ayudar o asesorar y disculpen las molestias pero no he buscado solución alguna a través de internet, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: [Activa la consola](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/javaconsole.html), no estoy seguro si funcionará desde el .exe, pero puedes probar desde un .jar.

Comment: @sal te comento que lo realice así equipo por equipo con el .jar y mostraba bien los reportes, pero en el .exe no lo muestra, no se a que se deberá, soy nuevo en estas lides y al aprender siempre surgen problemas pero como este no me había tocado, mañana en la tarde que llevo una semana en esto y no puedo solución, favor de ayudar y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: En launch4j establece *Header Type* a *console*, y lanza la aplicación desde la línea de comandos. La idea es ver los mensajes de consola para no adivinar.

Comment: @sal te comento que encontré un listado de errores los cuales te los muestro como imagen

Comment: En lugar de dejar un comentario tu solución, ponlo como respuesta (en base a [answer] y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer)). Recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Además, si no haces esto, [el usuario "Comunidad" se encargará de revivir la pregunta cada cierto tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452).

Comment: mis disculpas por el error cometido @padaleiana, no alcance leer esto en las especificaciones, no se volverá a repetir.

Comment: Se entiende, ¡pero no olvides responder a tu pregunta y aceptar tu respuesta! No lo dejes para una siguiente pregunta: podés corregir el error desde ya :)

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema similar hace unas semanas con subreportes, en el local funciona correctamente, pero al instalarlo en otra pc, sencillamente no funciona. El error data en las ubicaciones de las imágenes o subreportes que apunten a una dirección en específico, de alguna manera, Jasper no puede encontrar esa ubicación. La solución es que especifiques una ruta que TODAS las pc a las que se lo instales, la tengan, como por ejemplo ubicar todos tus reportes e imágenes en el disco C dentro de una carpeta que cree el instalador o tú mismo manualmente, así nunca te dará ese problema.

Te dejo este texto que encontré en un artículo en internet:

**"También podemos ejegir si queremos guardar la ruta del subreporte (para que el reporte maestro sepa donde buscarlo) como un parámetro llamado $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}, o como una ruta absoluta estática. Lo mejor es elegir está ultima ya que modificaremos la ruta para que busque el subreporte en en el mismo directorio que el reporte maestro. Así si los movemos de un directorio a otro, solo tendremos que preocuparnos de llevarnos los dos juntos."**

Adicionalmente, te comparto el artículo completo [aquí](https://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/04/creacion-de-reportes-con-jasperrepots-y_18.html)

Comment: Es _elegir_* :)

Comment: les aviso para @sal y Rodrigo, después de una semana de frustración, llegue a la conclusión que realice una carpeta con las imágenes en los 2 equipos de la red local colocando las imágenes y so saben que funciona, que alegría, se que no es una solución optima, pero al mal tiempo dale prisa, y muchas gracias a todos y por el tiempo que dedicaron a este pequeño ser humano, que Dios los bendiga a cada uno de uds., y sus seres queridos, es lo menos que se merecen y mil gracias nuevamente